# scale in script form play

Tags: html, scala, playframework

I've code like this, to create/edit Contact form. I need to get some values from model, if I'm editing form, and do nothing, if i'm creating new.

```
@(fieldForm: Form[MyModel])
@import helper._

@main("Create new") {
   @form(routes.Actions.createFieldHolder()) {

    <html>
        <head>
           <script>
              function funcOnLoadSubForm(){

                    @*
                    if(@fieldForm.get==null) {
                    ...
                    }
                    *@
                OR
                    @*
                    if(@fieldForm.get.equals(null)) {
                    ...
                    }
                    *@
                OR
                    @*
                    if(@fieldForm.get.eq(null)) {
                    ...
                    }
                    *@
                }
           </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="funcOnLoadSubForm()">

    </body
}
```

I always get an error : IllegalStateException: No value.

Answer (score 1):

The [API Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form) states that `get` will `return the concrete value, if the submission was a success.`. Since you are creating a new model you haven't submitted anything which means the data is empty and `get` will throw an exception.

You can fix this by using `foreach` on `fieldForm.value`. Example:

```
 <script>
    function funcOnLoadSubForm(){
        @fieldForm.value.foreach { data =>
            // Do something here if fieldForm was submitted
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand, why it's newer get into this code block. I fill it with : `MyModel row = MyModel.finder.byId(id);
                                                                                               Form<MyModel> rowForm = Form.form(MyModel.class).fill(row);`